# vNext, MVC6, MVC 6, dotnetcore. Which to search?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this. But is there a recommended name to use for searching issues to do with .net MVC 6?

I've been using it for a good few months now and generally search "mvc 6 whatever my issue is", and then if that doesn't work I add on "core vnext".

The term vNext doesn't seem to be used nearly as often despite this presumably what they had hoped people would use the most frequently? I'm presuming other versions of .net mvc have had the same issue of whether to include the space or not, but I doubt this effects the results returned by search engines too much?

Anyone know of any official references to what we should be searching/posting questions using? Or do they really want us to use the whole thing which seems like a longer name for no value..

Comment: `.net core {{issue}}` works fine for me

Comment: search for `asp.net core `

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/